# Creating Reset JButton?

Tags: java, jbutton, reset

I am trying to write code for a JButton that when clicked would reset a value. In this case it is the random value of a dice that I am trying to generate over and over with a new random value each time it is clicked. I know if I create a new instance of the class it will generate a different value, so perhaps I need to generate multiple instances? I really am trying to make this a situation where you can keep clicking the button and a new number will be generated until you quit.

```
class RollDice
{//Begin RollDice Class


//Initiate method rollDice
public static int rollDice(int number, int nSides)
{
    //System.out.println( "--- Welcome to the Dice Game v2! ---" ); // welcomes player

    Random r = new Random();
    //Declare class variables
    int num = 0;
    int roll = 0;

    if(nSides >= 3)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            roll = r.nextInt(nSides)+1;
            //System.out.println("Roll is: " + roll);
            num = num + roll;
        }
    }

    else
    {
        System.out.println("Error num needs to be from 3");
    }
    return num;
} //end method rollDice

int d4 = rollDice(1, 4);
int d6 = rollDice(1, 6);
int d8 = rollDice(1, 8);
int d10 = rollDice(1, 10);
int d12 = rollDice(1, 12);
int d20 = rollDice(1, 20);

public RollDice ()

{
    this.d4 = d4;
}

public void setD4 (int D4)
{
    this.d4 = D4;
}
public int getD4 ()
{
    return d4;
}
//////////////////  
{
    this.d6 = d6;
}

public void setD6 (int D6)
{
    this.d6 = D6;
}
public int getD6 ()
{
    return d6;
}
//////////////////
{
    this.d8 = d8;
}

public void setD8 (int D8)
{
    this.d8 = D8;
}
public int getD8 ()
{
    return d8;
}
//////////////////
{
    this.d10 = d10;
}

public void setD10 (int D10)
{
    this.d10 = D10;
}
public int getD10 ()
{
    return d10;
}
//////////////////
    {
    this.d12 = d12;
}

public void setD12 (int D12)
{
    this.d12 = D12;
}
public int getD12 ()
{
    return d12;
}
//////////////////
{
    this.d20 = d20;
}

public void setD20 (int D20)
{
    this.d20 = D20;
}
public int getD20 ()
{
    return d20;
}
//////////////////
}// End RollDice Class
```

Comment: What do you mean by `and pull the information again` reset should only clear the entries?

Comment: Great question, what I am attempting to do is make a game to help myself learn java and OOP. So what I am stuck on is creating a reset button. Example, I have a random number that gets generated by a method and displayed, and I want this "reset" button to clear the previous value and reuse that method to generate a new one.

Comment: The number of ways this might be achieved and near limitless, without further context, it's impossible to answer with any certainty

Comment: While I understand what you're attempting to do it's not at all clear what your code is doing - or even why it's all there. Do you really need all of this? Can you create a minimal example that describes what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you need to implement `ActionListener` than add action listener to `JButton`

```
JButton b = new JButton("RESET");
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    }
});
```

*Set all the entities of form or page to initial state.*

***FOR EXAMPLE***

- For `JTextField`  use  `jtextfield.setText("");`
- To get The data use `double d=Double.valueOf(jtextfield.getText());` so now you have old value .

So perform operation on old value store it to variable than clear textfield.